# Sending Data to Server in ObjectiveC

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am currently trying to send data from my xcode project to a server that I had made but the data doesn't seem to appear in my tables when I run my application.

It is quite simple, allowing the user to enter a name and a message which is sent when a button is pressed. I do not know what I've done wrong, any suggestions?

Here is my php code:

```
<?php

$username = "root";
$database = "testdb";

mysql_connect('localhost', $username);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die ("Unable to find database");

$name = @$_GET["name"];
$message = @$_GET["message"];

$query = "INSERT INTO test VALUES ('', '$name', '$message')";

mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error("error"));

mysql_close();

?>
```

and my obj c code:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define kPostURL @"http://localhost/TESTCONNECT.php" //variable to use whenever
#define kName @"name"
#define kMessage @"message"



@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UITextField *nameText;
IBOutlet UITextView *messageText;

NSURLConnection *postConnection;
}

-(IBAction)post:(id)sender;


@end
```

.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

}




-(void) postMessage:(NSString*) message withName:(NSString *) name{

if(name !=nil && message !=nil){

    NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kPostURL];
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kName, name]];

    [postString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kMessage, message]];

    [postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: postString]];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    postConnection =[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];


}
}

-(IBAction)post:(id)sender{
[self postMessage:messageText.text withName:nameText.text];
[messageText resignFirstResponder];
messageText.text=nil;
nameText.text=nil;

}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a post in objetive C, so in PHP you need to catch the variables with $_POST, not $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could actuall send a string to a php (POST) file. I think the rest should work. I didn't try it but it looks fine for me.

```
- (void) send {
    NSString *testString = @"this is a test";

    NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"message=%@",testString];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR/URL/test.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I manage to get it working. Quick question however: If I have multiple View Controllers with their own input boxes, would I need to create php files for EACH VC?

Comment: One file should be enough if you just work with the Post-vars that you receive:

e.g.

`$firstFile = $_POST["sentFromVC1"];
$secondFile = $_POST["sentFromVC2"];

if(firstFile) {
    echo "We received a string from ViewController1";
}

if(secondFile) {
    echo "We received a string from ViewController2";
}`